# Cannot establish connection between Azure Service App and Redis

Tags: asp.net, azure, redis, azure-web-app-service, redislabs

I'm trying to establish connection between **azure web app for containers** and **redis database**.
I have created a redis database using redislabs ([Redis Enterprise Cloud hosted in Azure](https://redislabs.com/cloud-partners/microsoft-azure/)) and free subscription plan.

I can connect to the redis db from my local machine, but I cannot from the docker container running in Azure.
I am not using TLS encryption because it's not supported by free subscription in database configuration.

Azure Service App location **is west europe**, redis **is east us**.

My application is asp.net 5 and here is my configuration. (I'm using StackExchange.Redis 5.0.0)

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(x =>
                {
                    x.ConfigurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
                    {
                        Password = config.Password,
                        EndPoints =
                        {
                            config.ConnectionString
                        },
                        KeepAlive = 180
                    };
                });
```

Here is an error that I have when trying to set a key in database.

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s).  There was an authentication failure; check that passwords (or client certificates) are configured correctly. AuthenticationFailure (None, last-recv: 231) on redis-18894.c251.east-us-mz.azure.cloud.redislabs.com:18894/Interactive, 
Flushed/ComputeResult, last: ECHO, origin: SetResult, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: ConnectedEstablishing, mgr: 9 of 10 available, 
last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.593.37019  
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImplAsync(Object configuration, TextWriter log) 
in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 823
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)  
at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.SetAsync(String key, Byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
```

May be I can only connect using TSL, because inside TLS/SSL settings in App Service I have
**Minimum TLS Version = 1.2**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

App service configuration is absolutely nothing to do with how you you're connecting to redis. Please make sure you use port 80 to connect to redis.
Please refer [this](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_csharp/) while making connection with redis.
using StackExchange.Redis;

readonly ConnectionMultiplexer muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("hostname:port,password=password");
IDatabase conn = muxer.GetDatabase();